# can binding work when using .template instead of .templateName in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, sproutcore-views

Binding HTML view to data works if I use `.templateName`: 
in html :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
TITLE, <b>{{pageTitle}}</b>
</script>
```

in js:

```
view.set('templateName','foo');
```

The generated HTML structure:

```
<div id="ember195" class="ember-view">
TITLE,
<b>
<script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder">
mainmenu
<script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder">
</b>
</div>
```

But if i use `.template` instead of `.templateName`:

```
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile('TITLE, <b>{{pageTitle}}</b>');
view.set('template',tmpl);
```

The generated HTML structure does not have placeholder tags around the `{{pageTitle}}` content and hence is not updated when pageTitle changes...

```
<div id="ember201" class="ember-view">
TITLE,
<b>mainmenu</b>
</div>
```

Is there anyway of using `.template` to still have binding work? Or do i have to use `.templateName`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your behavior. The following code outputs the same for every different view...

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
    TITLE, <b>{{App.pageTitle}}</b>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    Change the title: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="App.pageTitle"}}
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    pageTitle: 'my page title'
});

Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'foo'
}).append();

var view1 = Ember.View.create();
view1.set('templateName', 'foo');
view1.append();

Ember.View.create({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('TITLE, <b>{{App.pageTitle}}</b>')
}).append();

var view2 = Ember.View.create();
view2.set('template', Ember.Handlebars.compile('TITLE, <b>{{App.pageTitle}}</b>'));
view2.append();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/DTfMZ/

Comment: Thanks for posting that code! I was using `Handlebars.compile` instead of `Ember.Handlebars.compile`. Works correctly now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `defaultTemplate` in your view:

```
defaultTemplate: SC.Handlebars.compile('<label><input type="checkbox" {{bindAttr checked="value" disabled="disabled" tabindex="tabindex"}} > {{title}}</label>')
```

It has worked for me.